# Run time error 9 when using arrary in Macro

Tags: macros

I have been using the followng Macro and it works fine:

```
Sub PremTable()
Dim i, m, j As Integer
Dim PDFDiv, PDFClass, PDFSex, PDFPlan, LimAge As Variant
Dim FlagD, FlagC, Band, FlagP, FlagB, IssAge, Dur As Integer
PDFClass = Array("N", "S")
PDFSex = Array("M", "F")
PDFDiv = Array("G", "E")
PDFPlan = Array(10, 20, 30)
LimAge = Array(70, 60, 50)

j = 0
For FlagD = 1 To 2
Range("div").Value = PDFDiv(FlagD)
For FlagP = 1 To 3
Range("plan").Value = PDFPlan(FlagP)
For Band = 1 To 3
Range("band").Value = Band
For FlagS = 1 To 2
Range("sex").Value = PDFSex(FlagS)
For FlagC = 1 To 2
Range("class").Value = PDFClass(FlagC)
m = 18
For i = 1 To Range("LimAge").Value - 17
    Range("IssAge").Offset(i + j, 0) = m
    Range("age").Value = Range("IssAge").Offset(i + j, 0)
    Worksheets("input").Range("J4:J76").Copy
    Worksheets("Premium Tables").Range("M1").Offset(i + j, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues,         Transpose:=True
    Range("DIV2").Offset(i + j, 0) = Range("Div")
    Range("PLAN2").Offset(i + j, 0) = Range("plan")
    Range("BAND2").Offset(i + j, 0) = Range("band")
    Range("SEX2").Offset(i + j, 0) = Range("sex")
    Range("CLASS2").Offset(i + j, 0) = Range("class")
m = m + 1
Next i
j = j + i - 1
Next FlagC
Next FlagS
Next Band
Next FlagP
Next FlagD

End Sub
```

Now I have another very similar spreatsheet that I want to use this macro to creat tables, but it always give me the "run time error 9" for all of the arrays having text format variables (for example: Range("class").Value = PDFClass(FlagC) causing an runtime error 9)
Please advise! Thanks very much!

Comment: (next time, it would be better to include the error message; for example "Subscript out of range" is much more descriptive than error 9). Your problem is what the errors says: you are trying indices beyond the limits of the arrays. For example: PDFClass = Array("N", "S") has a dimension of 2, that is, only exist PDFClass(0) and PDFClass(1) but in your code you are intending to retrieve PDFClass(2) -> this is what triggers your error.

Comment: Thanks so much!! The problem has been resolved. I'm not familiar with arrays and now am wondering why the old macro could wrok with the wrong dimension...

Comment: No problem. VBA is a bit confusing for the array dimensions as far as most of the in-built collections start from 1. Bear in mind that if you declare the same array in a different way (Dim PDFClass(2) as String), its size becomes 3 and thus PDFClass(2) does work. As said, pretty confusing :)

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful! I will do more research myself :-)